# How to use typehinting to fetch an object's data without instantiating a class

Tags: php, oop, routes, closures, type-hinting

I have seen this example in frameworks like silex, symfony and I am not sure how it is done.

basically, I would like to get the content id `Request` <del>without instantiating it</del> hiding the instantiation part and simply call the class via a functions argument.

Here is a basic example.

```
<?php 

class Request {
    function get($key){
        $_GET[$key] = 42; 
        return $_GET[$key]; 
    }
}

$route = function(Request $request){
    // how to '42' without instanciating Request here
    var_dump($request->get('..'));
};

var_dump($route);
```

Comment: Read on "service containers" :)

Comment: You can start with a very basic one like Pimple to get your bearings.

Comment: Are you asking how to use type-hinting in your IDE for the $route variable?

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko I meant how to access methods of Request inside the function without instanciating it

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand. Try adding an example of the code you want to have and maybe I'll be able to help.

Comment: he wants to instantiate an object using the service container / locator pattern.

Comment: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/services.html